# Enable cgroups v1 in RaspberryPi OS

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

i am using a Raspbi 4 with the newest OS 32bit lite.
The OS is using cgroups v2
Due to some software limitations i need the cgroups v1.
I've added `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 swapaccount=1`
but nothing happens still v2 is active.

How can i change it ?

Comment: *"The OS is using cgroups v2"*  According to `man cgroups`: "Although  cgroups  v2  is intended as a replacement for cgroups v1, the older system continues to exist (and for compatibility reasons is unlikely to be removed).  Currently, cgroups v2 implements only a subset of the controllers available in cgroups v1.  The two systems are implemented so that both v1 controllers and v2 controllers can be mounted on the same system..."

Comment: "...Thus, for example, it is possible to use those controllers  that are  supported under version 2, while also using version 1 controllers where version 2 does not yet support those controllers.  The only restriction here is that a controller can't be simultaneously employed in both a cgroups v1 hierarchy and in the cgroups v2 hierarchy." To me this says you shouldn't have to do anything, although I admit I've probably only ever used the v2 interface.  Are you sure this isn't an  [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)?

Comment: @goldilocks Yes it can be: The AWS ECS Agent (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_agent.html) is yelling at me that i need cgroupsv1 but cgroups v2 is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

You should add `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` to your `/boot/cmdline.txt` or `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`

Before:

```
#findmnt -lo source,target,fstype,options -t cgroup,cgroup2
SOURCE  TARGET         FSTYPE  OPTIONS
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot
```

After adding `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` and reboot:

```
#findmnt -lo source,target,fstype,options -t cgroup,cgroup2
SOURCE  TARGET                          FSTYPE  OPTIONS
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified          cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd          cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio            cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset           cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/devices          cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer          cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event       cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct      cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct
cgroup  /sys/fs/cgroup/pids             cgroup  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids
```